# How to do subsequent calls on same url via Nock having different status code

Tags: node.js, sinon, nock

Problem:
I want to mock a situation in which on the same http call I get different results. Specifically, the first time it fails.
To some extent this is similar to [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) capability of `stub.onFirstCall()`, `stub.onSecondCall()`
Expectation:
I expected that if I use `once` on the first call and `twice` on the second call I would be able to accomplish the above.

```
nock( some_url )
    .post( '/aaaa', bodyFn )
    .once()
    .reply( 500, resp );
nock( some_url )
    .post( '/aaaa', bodyFn )
    .twice()
    .reply( 200, resp );
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way is to simply 
call `Nock` twice.

```
nock( some_url )
    .post( '/aaaa', bodyFn )
    .reply( 500, resp );
nock( some_url )
    .post( '/aaaa', bodyFn )
    .reply( 200, resp );
```

The way Nock works is that each call registers an interceptor for `some_url`.
In fact the first time you call `some_url` will clear the first interceptor and so on.

as stated in [docs](https://github.com/nock/nock#read-this---about-interceptors):

> When you setup an interceptor for a URL and that interceptor is used,
>   it is removed from the interceptor list. This means that you can
>   intercept 2 or more calls to the same URL and return different things
>   on each of them. It also means that you must setup one interceptor for
>   each request you are going to have, otherwise nock will throw an error
>   because that URL was not present in the interceptor list. If you don’t
>   want interceptors to be removed as they are used, you can use the
>   .persist() method.